# Apache LocationMatch with regex does not work as expected

Tags: regex, apache

I am trying to redirect URLs with a specific pattern but want to exlude URLs that follow a specific pattern (in this case, containing either `api/read`, `api/write` or `api/delete`)

in `sso_saml.conf` I try to match these two cases with the following patterns:

```
<LocationMatch "^/abc/(?!(api/write|api/read|api/delete))">
  ....
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch "^/abc/api/(read|write|delete)">
  ...
</LocationMatch>
```

Still, calling `http://myurl/abc/api/read` does not do what I expect, but rather gets matched by the first expression which should exclude it.

Both regular expressions work with online tools for regex testing as I expect them.

From the documentation, it looks like masking of slashes is not necessary, but even if I mask them (with a `\`), that does not change anything.

---

Alternatively, I would be thankful for any hints how to debug this, i.e. how to prove whether a pattern was matched or not

---

The same behaviour even occurs when I drastically simplify the pattern:

```
<LocationMatch "^/abc/(?!(api)">
  ....
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch "^/abc/api">
  ...
</LocationMatch>
```

Whether I call `http://myurl/abc/api` or `http://myurl/abc/somethingelse` - the executed behaviour is always that of the first LocationMatch, the one which captures everything but `abc/api`. This applies as well when I change the order of the two tags.

Comment: Does it need the start of string/line `^` ?

Comment: does not have an impact